# Grsync - Delete on Destination

Tags: rsync, delete, grsync

I am running Grsync on Ubuntu 16.04.  I have never had trouble before but now notice that the destination is much larger than than the source and the problem appears to be that files deleted on source are not deleted on destination.  Any tips as to what might be going on?  Here is my setup -

rsync -r -t -p -o -g -v --progress --delete --size-only -u -l -H -ignore-errors /home/brett/ /media/brett/godpod_backup/brett

[image]

[image]

Comment: is the destination the same format as the source? ie are they both ext4 or is the target a NTFS or fat32 format?

Comment: source and target are ext4.

Comment: I don't know why you've checked *skip newer* or included  *ignore errors*. Not a good idea if what you're trying to do is produce an identical back-up to your source folders and files which is what most users intend. Also there should be a `/` at the end of the target folder.

Comment: adding a trailing forward slash would copy only the contents of the source directory (/brett) and not /brett.

Comment: No. It copies parent folder Brett **and** its contents (subfolders and files). If Brett doesn't already exist it creates it.

Comment: ... so why isn't Grsync deleting destination files that are no longer in source?

Comment: Could be because it's clashing with your *--ignore-errors* option. Without seeing the run output it's difficult to say. I would delete that option and *skip newer*, delete the whole back-up, including parent folder, add `/` at end of target path, then do another back-up. After that try deleting a file from source, then see if it is removed from back-up in a dry run.

Comment: Lesson learned "Ignore Existing" overrides "Delete on Destination".  Turning off "Ignore Existing" and turning on "Delete on Destination" deletes files/directories on destination that are no longer on source.  Thanks all for the help.